# Show status bar when hide navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, navbar, statusbar

I hide navbar when user scrolls the table up.

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden == false {
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
    }
}
```

But this method also hides the status bar.

Can't keep my status bar. These methods don't work:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarHidden(false, withAnimation: .None)
prefersStatusBarHidden()
```

Please, help!

Comment: Go to info.plist and add two attributes if not present. set "Status bar is initially hidden" to NO and set UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance to NO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was my mistake. Status bar wasn't hidden, it was just white like a table view background. Just set this when nav bar is hidden:

```
UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .default
```

Answer (score 5):

if you are want to hide and show just navigation bar on scrollView.

you can `override viewDidAppear`. & use `hidesBarsOnSwipe` property of navigation controller.

> override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
>
> ```
>     super.viewDidAppear(animated)
>     
>     navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
>
> }
> ```

Hope This Answer helps you.

Answer (score 3):

Try make a variable `shouldHideStatusBar`

And override this func:

```
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return shouldHideStatusBar
}
```

when scroll put it:

```
shouldHideStatusBar = true/false
self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
```

Hope this help.